# Using webbrowser to click on a button in a webpage

Tags: c#, browser, html, getelementbyid, invokemember

so what I need to do is to use this code:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("www.somthing.com");
browser.Document.GetElementById("ID").InvokeMember("click");
```

and then i need to find the id of the button in the page and put in my code but my problem is some of the buttons don't have Id's! what should I do then? they only have type and class and some other things but no Id. i realized that some buttons might be java and maybe that's why i can't click on them by the usual way. so do you know what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said your button element has a `className` ,you can get this element with like this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("To your register account url");
        }
        int on = 0;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "yourclassname")
                {
                    btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```