# Click button inside web browser programmatically c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I would like to click a button of a webpage within a web browser.

I know I can do this when I have the Id/Class from the button but I don't have the Id/Class in this case (or it is the same for all buttons).

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="option" value="0">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="option" value="1">Button 2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="option" value="2">Button 3</button>
</form>
```

Lets say I would like to click Button 3. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is. Is this `asp.net`?

Comment: Why not just give them an id?...

Comment: @Sayse `but I don't have the Id/Class in this case (or it is the same for all buttons)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Those button's haven't been given an id at all, i'm suggesting they probably need one

Comment: @DrewKennedy I want to do this with .net (c#)

Comment: Okay, could be. @Sayse...

Comment: @Gewoo Check my answer and tell me if it helps.

Comment: Do you have any access to the UI? Can you make changes?

Comment: @Gewoo Can you share us your C# Code that generates this bit?

Comment: @PraveenKumar My c# code did not generated this. This is an existing web page wich is in a webBrowser control

Comment: WinForms or WPF WebBrowser control?

Comment: @Gewoo Oh... I am not sure about how to access stuff inside Web Browser control. I will leave my answer here. If that doesn't help at all, let me know, I will delete it. `:)`

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334909/using-webbrowser-to-click-on-a-button-in-a-webpage) *may* be of some help.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi WinForms

Comment: @DrewKennedy Thanks for linking that question!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `nth-child()`. So in your case, you might need to do:

```
$(function () {
  $("form button:nth-child(3)").trigger("click");
});
```

**Note:**

1. You can't use server side C# code to interact with the UI.
2. You need to use JavaScript to do it.
3. Add jQuery to use the functions given above.

**Adding jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `You need to use JavaScript to do it.` Not true. If this is in .NET, he could make it work with C#.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Well, how? Only JavaScript will have the access to do the UI right?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Yup i'm using .net

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Selenium` and `WebDriver` to do it:

```
//this will click on button 3. You can also use "0" or "1" for the other buttons
string value = "2"; 
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[value='" + value + "']")).Click();
```

This will click on the button by the `value` attribute.

Download from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Guide how to add Selenium to visual studio [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_dotnet_driver_client.jsp).